# How do i move the UILabel Depending on UISlider

Tags: ios, swift

How do I change the origin y of the UILabel depending on UISlider?

If the slider value is more than 1.5 labels, it should move back to its position or move down. I want to change the **y** origin depending on the scroll of UISlider value.

[image: sample of UI]

Until now I have tried this but it's not effective.

The below function is `valueChanged` method of `UISlider`:

```swift
internal func valueChanged(value: Float) {
  if value > 1.0 && value < 1.5 {
    let view = self.viewWithTag(400) as ! UIImageView
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, CGFloat(value - 0.5), CGFloat(value - 0.5))
    let label = self.viewWithTag(500) as ! UILabel
    if value > lastValue {
      label.frame.origin.y = (label.frame.origin.y + CGFloat(value - 0.5))
    }
    if value < lastValue {
      label.frame.origin.y = (label.frame.origin.y - CGFloat(value - 0.5))
    }
  } else {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1) {
      let view = self.viewWithTag(400) as ! UIImageView
      view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, CGFloat(1.0), CGFloat(1.0))
    }
  }
}
```

I know it's a wrong approach.

Comment: Could you post some more code that shows how the above is linked to actions on the slider?

Comment: You need to set label's frame into variable first, and set it back after change the y value. `label.frame` here is a getter method instead of `setter`.

Comment: Your approach seems to be correct based on the code you have shown, but more context would be helpful.

Comment: @xi.lin But you can set the origin the way he has done. It is not a read-only field.

Comment: one note: you have to disable autolayout if you want to manipulate origin directly.

Comment: @Sparky i have updated the code

Comment: @xi.lin i have updated the code

Comment: @Benjamin Lowry i have updated the code

Comment: @Rok Jarc i have updated the code

Comment: @BenjaminLowry Just test the code in Objective-C that will complain about `Expression is not assignable`. But it works in Swift.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry I tested it keeps on moving down not that effective any other solution for moving with content offset or value?

Comment: @O-mkar moving the origin is likely going to be your best solution, perhaps debug your code and figure out why it is moving down repeatedly

Comment: @BenjaminLowry when i move the slider fast it it keeps on adding y offset. do you know how to limit max y origin value